# Unable to find msbuild after building Mono 6.10 on linux

Tags: linux, msbuild, mono

Yeah there's a need for me to build MS project on Linux.
I've download Mono from their offical website and built on Ubuntu 16. But when I want to use msbuild ,I found this tool didn't exist.
After my "make && make install", the folder of msbuild in Mono is:

```
hololqq@hololqq-virtual-machine:/opt/mono/lib/mono/msbuild$ ls
Current
```

Compare to the Mono installed by using apt-get , the folder should be:

```
hololqq@hololqq-virtual-machine:/usr/lib/mono/msbuild$ ls
15.0  Current
```

It's strange because the document : https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/6.10.0/ has said that they just update msbuild:

19662 - [2019-12] Bump msbuild to track mono-2019-12

So I'm confused with this situation. Is anything else I forget while building? Or just the source codes of Mono didn't contain msbuild? Appericiate for your any suggestion.

PS:I have used monodevelop and xbuild. And monodevelop isn't easy to build from source code, and xbuild has some bugs while compiling VS peojects.

Update:
Finally still has no useful way. I use xbuild instead(it has a bug that you need to run it twice, because the first build won't success).

Comment: It is not quite clear, but Mono does have its own MSBuild fork, https://github.com/mono/msbuild You shouldn't attempt to build your own Mono from source, as there isn't enough documentation around that.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your answer! I have tried that fork,and now it works...with root permission.Only with root permission can msbuild works..It's so strange,I needs to check it more.

Comment: Then you can post/accept your own answer. BTW, keep in mind you should migrate to .NET Core/.NET 5 as early as possible.